# F#: FS0001 - This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type'unit'

Tags: f#

I am attempting to run the code from this excellent article: [Finding solutions using genetic algorithms in F#](https://industrialdotnet.wordpress.com/2017/05/17/finding-solutions-using-genetic-algorithms-in-f/)

Frustratingly, it reports an FS0001 error, as follows:

> This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'unit'

It omplains that the very last line of the code is incorrect:

```
evolve 1000 0 initialPopulation
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're trying to compile as one block of code, either in here or a GitHub gist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:  "main" must return int. Add a line with just "0" at the end of it.